# Can a "spoiler" be used to hide a video?

Tags: support

I've seen "spoilers" on some sites, where the text or picture is "hidden" behind some sort of box. If you hover over the box, you can see what's under it. The point is that if you don't want to see it, for one reason or another, you just avoid hovering.

Usually there's also some text discussing the subject matter of the picture. If you don't want to see it, you just scroll past the spoiler.

It's good for when you're interested in the post, just not a certain image or some wording.

Is that something that can be done to a video, so we could choose to read the question or answer but not have to see the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, see here [Spoiler Tagging for videos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280961/spoiler-tagging-for-videos)
although it would be possible to do it gifs.

The other thing is that some users will get annoyed at having to to mouse over to see something behind a spoiler markup just like how sometimes certain users get annoyed at having to scroll down to read the answer...